# How to sign the assembly in Visual Studio Team Services Build definition

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, clickonce, code-signing, azure-pipelines

I need to create a build definition in Team Services, previously Visual Studio Online, where i want to sign my assembly and manifest file after build.

Basically i will have a key file in my server, which i want to load and sign my assemblies and manifest files for click-once application.

Could you please help me on this how to do?

Note: *I know this manually going to visual studio project properties->signing tab and select checkbox options and publish, but i want to do as part of my build definition*

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box in VSTS you're probably using a hosted agent, which is just a server with TFS installed on it that builds the solution.

Since you'll need your code signing certificate installed on the build server you'll need to connect your own agent to VSTS which has TFS installed on it. The upside to using your own build server is you get maximum flexibility, but you have to maintain that infrastructure.

In the past this is the route that I had to take in order to build and sign a clickonce for an Outlook addin.